# How to make my iOS project source-closed while it must use open source code?

Tags: gpl, gpl-3

My colleague and I are writing a software named hin2n-ios, which is an implementation of n2n (a peer to peer VPN software) on iOS platform. So it is inevitable to call or use the code of n2n.

the n2n software is under GPLv3. But I don't want to make our software ( main project at least ) under GPLv3 or open-source by some reasons. Is it possible ?

By the way, the hin2n-ios is almost developed.

Comment: Apple APP Store may refuse our software if we choose GPLv3. Which is a part of the reason why we want to make it source-closed.

Comment: it is a misconception that apple rejects apps purely because they are released under the GPL. you can go ahead and use the correct license required by your third party components.

Comment: Would you be okay with releasing your source code under either the Apache 2.0 or MIT license? Those licenses are both fine for the App Store, and doing so might make the n2n developers more likely to grant you an exception than they would if you insist on it being closed source.

Comment: I've contacted author of n2n, Luca Deri, and he asked me which license will be acceptable by both Apple and us. It looks like MIT or Apache license is the choice.

Comment: @gemini your overall program cannot be MIT or Apache if it contains GPL code. Your own code can be MIT or Apache, but that's not the actual program, is it? That's just one part of the program.

Comment: @user253751 The context of that comment was getting an exception to the GPL from n2n's author.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nearly no way if we talk GPL.

If you use GPLv3 code in your project or you use it for reference for a re-implementation or port, you are bound by the license. That's the point of a license: you are given permission to use the code on the conditions stated in the license. Without license you would not have legal access to use it at all.

If you call the n2n code via library calls or copy code from that project into your project, you are bound. If n2n offers a well-defined public API and operates as a separate programme, available separately and which you call, then you can interact with it via API and not be bound by its license (then it's a mere aggregation).

The implementation state of your software is insubstantial for this question as is a limitation by whatever app store - that's why you should consider licensing questions before you do any work so that you can possibly work around copyright issues, like choosing different libraries to rely on or implementing a library with a similar effect in a clean room re-implementation process.

Apple does a big dis-service to the community with its app store guidelines, but there is no legal way to put code exclusively GPL-licensed in Apple's app store (I tried. They flat-out refuse and removed it from the app store): It is problematic as the app store puts additional restrictions on the usage in its TOS which are not compatible with the GPL (see [this summary](https://www.fsf.org/blogs/licensing/more-about-the-app-store-gpl-enforcement) by the FSF). You will have to get a license exceptions by the n2n authors - or re-implement a similar library without ever looking at the n2n code (cleanroom implementation) - a thing you probably cannot do anymore as you are aquainted with its code.

Comment: Then how can I get a license exception by the n2n authors ? Apparently I can't re-write the n2n code for I'm very familiar with the original source code.

Comment: You probably can't, because people who use the GPL generally want to keep their software free.  As planetmaker notes, this is an Apple-created problem, and not something anyone except them can fix.  We can only encourage you to develop for less free-software-hostile platforms instead.

Comment: @gemini: "Then how can I get a license exception by the n2n authors ?" – Ask them for one.

Comment: Asking is the only way. But as you will need permission from ALL contributors... that will be exceedingly hard. On GitHub I count 45 unique contributors. So I believe the chance that they actually CAN give you one is very very slim.

Comment: More than that, Apple can't _permit_ it. Somebody tried it with Gnu GO long ago. Apple got served with a lawsuit demanding the signing key because they were distributing GPL v3 software that was hardware locked by a signing key.

Comment: thanks @Joshua. I added a link to a summary explanation on that topic by the FSF

Comment: Note that with "mere aggregation" the overall license of the aggregation still has to allow people to use the GPL part under the GPL terms! That means you still have to release the source code, etc. It negates the virality that makes the GPL apply to your own code, but not the licence itself.

Comment: @user253751 sure thing. And that makes use in the app store due to its TOS bascially impossible - as the same upload problem arises as if the whole project was GPL.

Comment: @planetmaker Paid open source apps are impossible due to a direct conflict between Apple's T&C's (any payment is for the license) and GPL (you cannot charge for the license). Apart from that, an app can be dual licensed - and it shouldn't be difficult to build an app that includes the complete source code. Click a button, and the complete source code gets sent to your email as an attachment. Not difficult to do. ("Dual license": You must allow the user to do anything that Apple's license allows them, like download on six devices in your family, but you also must allow the user anything GPL ...

Comment: ... allows them to do, like getting the source code, and porting it to Android, for example. GPL licensed obviously and following whatever terms Android has. But obviously if this library has 45 copyright holders, ONE of them will complain to Apple, and the app is gone from the app store.

Comment: @gnasher729 you cannot attach another license to a GPL-licensed project without every contributor's consent. That is impossible to get for large projects with many contributors like n2n seems to be - unless they have a CLA which allows the maintainers or a board to decide to do so.

Comment: @gnasher729 Where in the world did you get the idea that you can't charge for GPL'd software?  Point to where that is stated in the license.  Do you mean GPL clause 11? 
 Otherwise, clarify what you mean, please.

Comment: @MarcWilson He didn't say you can't charge for the _software_; he said "you cannot charge for the _license._" That's from 2.b: "You must cause any work that you distribute or publish...to be licensed as a whole at no charge to all third parties under the terms of this License."

Comment: I think I'd be interested in seeing a lawyer test this bit from Apple's terms "unless that App Store Product is covered by a valid end user license agreement between you and the Application Provider of that App Store Product, in which case the terms of that separate end user license agreement will govern." (from https://www.apple.com/legal/macapps/stdeula/).  But I am CERTAINLY not a lawyer.  It's all just theoretical.

Comment: @MarcWilson: According to GPL, you can charge whatever you want for the software, reasonable cost for the source code, and NOTHING for the license. According to the AppStore T&Cs, any payment is not for the software, but for the license. GPL software on the AppStore must conform with both, therefore no payment is possible.

Comment: @planetmaker A "license" is what you allow others to do. As the software developer, you _must_ allow people to do what the GPL license allows or you can't distribute the GPL app. And you _must_ allow people to do what the AppStore license allows or you can't distribute the app on the AppStore. The AppStore allows you to allow another license at the same time. And I can't see anything in the GPL that stops you from giving users more rights as long as they don't conflict with the GPL.

Answer (score 1):

You have some very strong misconceptions about the AppStore.

Apple won't reject your app because it is opensourced (just add the open source license as your own license). BUT Apple will reject your app if one of the copyright holders complains. Including the copyright holders of the original open source code. That's not because there would be anything wrong with your app (only some expensive lawyers can decide that) but because Apple doesn't want to be involved in anything that could go to court.

If you publish your app as opensource, the copyright holders might complain. Or they might not complain. Whether they are right or wrong, I couldn't decide. However, if you publish NOT as opensource, then 1. they WILL complain and your app WILL disappear from the app store, and 2. If they sue you for copyright infringement, they will win.

In addition, note that you can't put opensource code on the AppStore for money. That's because Apple on one hand says that any payment is not for the app itself, but for the license to use it, and GPL on the other hand says that you can charge any amount for the app itself, and a reasonable amount for the source code, but you can NOT charge for the license. Therefore, any open source app on the app store must be free (as in free beer).

@Joshua: Nobody knows if Apple can or cannot permit it, but if a copyright holder complains (and the open source authors are usually copyright holders), then Apple will remove the app. So are you sure that a lawsuit actually happened? Note that for any open source app, you can demand the source code, and recompile it on your own computer, without needing any keys.

Comment: This would be better if you didn't assume that "GPL" licensed code was the only possible type of "open source" software. The wording here, particularly in your fourth paragraph, makes the assumption that GPL is the only thing that "open source" can be, which is blatantly false. The GPL is merely one, of many, licenses which are commonly used for open source software. The various licenses, of course, have different requirements. While the OP is, obviously, concerned about using GPL licensed code, the wording here goes too far in generalizing over all open source software.